# Java - Advanced Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two Threads, `ThreadA` (Main) with the methods `j()` and `k(){...j()...}` and a second Thread, `ThreadB`. ThreadA randomly calls method `k()`, which, among others, calls method `j()`. `ThreadB` randomly calls method `j()`.

Now method `k()` and `j()` can not be executed at the same time as they share variables.

How can I make sure that `ThreadB` is only able to call method `j()` if `ThreadA` is not currently executing method `k()`? And also that `ThreadB` will execute `j()` after `ThreadA` finished executing `k()`.

I read about the synchronized keyword but it seems that it can only cover one method. (e.g. ThreadX and ThreadY both access method `m()`).

Comment: please share your code with us

Comment: Also, locks are reentrant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504231/reentrancy-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I would use the mechanism of synchronized statements and intrinsic locks. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html). You can synchronize both methods using synchronized statements pointing to the same object.